# Page doesn't redirect correctly

Tags: python, django

I'm learning django with myself and when I was following the tutorial [Writing your first Django app, part 4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial04/) today, I met this problem.(I'm using django 1.9.7 and Python 3.5.2 64-bit and PyCharm)

When I select a choice and click the button Vote, it supposes to be redirected to the results page, but I get the error message:"You didn't select a choice" which is supposes to occur when I don't select any choices all the time. And I have checked my codes, I figured something must went wrong with the function vote, but I don't know the reason.

polls\view.py

```
def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except(KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results',args=(question.id,)))
```

polls\urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name = 'index'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

polls\template\polls\detail.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" methon="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why don't you use form to parse posted data?

Comment: Remove the try/except and see what actual error Django is encountering.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman I can't remove neither try or except without getting syntax error

Comment: Remove try, except and else, and additionally remove the code that was inside the except block, leaving only the code that was inside try.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman  I did and it gives `MultiValueDictKeyError at /polls/1/vote/`

Comment: OK. For some reason it's not seeing the values passed in from the post. Can you now do `print(request.POST)` at the top of the view and see what it says?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman sorry, pychram suggests `Unresolved reference 'request'`

Comment: You have to do it inside the view function.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman do you mean vote function? and I did it inside vote function but when I run view.py, it gives `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xuziwei/mysite/polls/views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .models import Question, Choice
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for wasting all your time. It was a typo which caused the problem.

polls\template\polls\detail.html
`<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" methon="post">`

`methon` should be `method`, and the problem has been solved.